# как задать xsi:type у объекта в zeep

Tags: python-2.x, soap

Есть soap клиент под питон - zeep.

Используя его, передаю данные в сервис. Проблема в том, что сервис требует указать атрибут xsi:type у того объекта в который все запаковывается.

Передача объекта выглядит вот так:

```
ambCase = {'data1':'value1',
           'data2':'value2'}
client = zeep.Client(wsdl=WSDL_Address)
result = client.service.MethodName(GUID, {'CaseDto':ambCase})
```

Все бы хорошо, вот только zeep задает тип объекта по умолчанию string(т.е. xsi:type = 'xsd:string'), а нужен 'a:CaseAmb'. Можно ли как-то задать xsi:type у передаваемого объекта? Пошарившись по сайту разработчиков с документацией ничего путного не нашел

Answer (score 1, accepted):

методом проб и ошибок была вычислена следующая комбинация:

```
objectType = client.get_type('ns6:someTypeName') #указываем тип объекта, xml атрибут xsi:type
objectWrap = xsd.Element('xmlTagName',objectType) # xmlTagName - название xml-тега
objectValue = objectWrap('param1',param2,param3[0]) # заполняем объект данными
client = zeep.Client(wsdl)
result = client.service.MethodName(objectValue) #передаем созданный объект как параметр
```

Как я понял, если передать в zeep словарь, то zeep сам собирает такой объект без указания типа, а если необходимо указать тип, то надо собирать объект самому